# Remove UITabBar item inside didSelect function

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Why I cannot remove tab bar item with index 0 when I select it. If I select tab. bar item 1 it will delete item 0 without any problems

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem){
   super.viewDidLoad()

    ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 let arr =  ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers

 let v1:UIViewController  = arr [1]

 let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage") 

 ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers = [homePage,v1]
```

Update : remove

```
  super.viewDidLoad()
```

call in the function as it may cause weird results , even it's not it's place to declare

Comment: I get this error: Value of type '[UIViewController]?' has no member 'remove'

Comment: new error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: i think u have two baritems that u want to hide one of them

Comment: this code pass on if statement, did not go to the else at all. Again error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: root view controller with internal weak static var tabBarViewController:UITabBarController?

Comment: with self I have this error: Value of type 'TabBarViewController' has no member 'tabBarViewController'

Comment: The interesting thing is that this code ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: 0) works perfect if I click on second tab bar item but if I click on first one (with index 0) then I receiving these beyond bounds errors

Comment: this solution actually keeps only one tab bar item on the tab bar but what I want to achieve is to remove one vc and insert another one on the same place.

Comment: I have even code for inserting new one: 
 let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage")
        ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?.insert(homePage!, at: 0)

Comment: error: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: i think that exception is in one of the vcs u want to show , can u screen shot where it points to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165255/discussion-between-ognjen-and-sh-khan).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will actually solve you problem. I have worked on setting a tab bar Items with my custom controllers when I decided to perform segue programmatically rather than from storyboard and I actually had a rough experience achieving that. What you need to do is: 
   **Instead of**

```
ContainerVC.tabBarViewController?.viewControllers?.remove(at: 0)
```

**Use**

```
self.viewControllers?.remove(at: 0)
```

I believe that will solve your problem.

Comment: This is not a solution, see my comments on previous answer